# SetWindowText Slow, Win32 C++

Tags: winapi, user-interface

I've got a simple application where I'm reading some internal variables and posting them to EditControl's on a menu.

Here is a code snippet

```
case 0:
        SetWindowText(GetDlgItem( gHWnd, IDC_PACKETID ), 
                     (LPSTR)std::to_string(long long(NC->mPacketNum)).c_str());
        break;
```

So there's a lot going on there. I'm just trying to convert a number to something that can be shown in the edit dialog. This is so slow, that I can drop from 50Hz to about 30Hz just by entering this section.

Any ideas to speed this up significantly?

Comment: That line of code could be greatly simplyfied by using `SetDlgItemInt`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I also tried LPCTSTR(NC->mPacketNum), which works fine, except when that variable is changed to a float.

Comment: Any simplification for float based things? Or is it going to be a SetDlgItemText thing, with a float to text conversion.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's an MS-provided wrapper for floating point numbers.  `SetDlgItemText` still saves the separate `GetDlgItem` though.

Comment: I wrote a quicky test to profile SetWindowText, it took 78 microseconds.  Use a proper profiler to find the problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: Tried that.... it shows 39% of the time spent in DispatchMessageA, which disappears if I stop doing this.

Comment: @HansPassant: What timer did you use to get that good of a resolution? I can't find anything reliable that is better than 10ms. Even the boost timer is garbage on this machine (Intel, Win 7).

Comment: Don't measure one call, see how long 100,000 calls take.

Answer (score 3):

There *is* quite a lot going on in that code.

It seems unlikely that SetWindowText itself is the slow part.  Let's take it apart piece by piece and see where the time may be going.  (The only way to know for sure is to profile, but I can't do that for you, so I'm looking at possibilities.  It's up to you to measure.)

```
SetWindowText(GetDlgItem( gHWnd, IDC_PACKETID ), 
              (LPSTR)std::to_string(long long(NC->mPacketNum)).c_str());
```

1. The GetDlgItem call *might* be sending messages to walk the child windows of gHWnd.  If there are many children, and if IDC_PACKETID is not one of the first ones, this could cost some time.  Consider computing this once and caching the result.  The HWND won't change unless you destroy the control and create a new one.
2. You're calling SetWindowText with an ASCII string.  (Why are you casting the result?  And, especially, why are you casting away the const-ness?)  If you're on a modern version of Windows, then your ASCII string is being converted to a wide string on the fly, which could involve additional dynamic memory management.  You could call SetWindowTextW (note the W suffix) and compute the wide string directly with std::to_wstring.  Depending on the implementation details of std::to_wstring, this could be faster.
3. Is the window really an edit control?  If you're changing it at 30-50 Hz, it seems unlikely that you need a full-fledged edit control.  Can you use a static text control instead?  It might have a simpler and faster implementation.
4. Is NC->mPacketNum going to be properly aligned for a long long?  If it's not aligned, this can adversely affect performance.  See if you can guarantee alignment.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try all that. Playing with the profiler now. McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention doesn't like it, but I'm figuring out ways to make it work. Thanks for the help. I'll post back when I get the time reduced so that others know what the answer is.

Answer (score 2):

I have gotten around this type of problem by maintaining a timestamp of the last window update. I would then prevent another update unless a certain amount of time had passed. 1/10th of a second seemed to work pretty well for me. Performance improved noticeably and updates still looked smooth.

Comment: Thanks.... did that, but it is each call that is terribly expensive, not the accumulation. Trying suggestions from above, it will likely be one thing I'm doing that is causing grief.

Answer (score 1):

For high frame rates, you'll want to use Direct2D or OpenGL rendering, not the built-in EDIT window class.

If you don't need a high frame rate, just high throughput, you could do `InvalidateRect` and only change the text when you get a PAINT message.  Windows will limit the rate it sends you `WM_PAINT`.  Or use a timer.  In this way you just store the new value in an internal variable and when you get a paint or timer callback, move it from the interval variable to the EDIT control.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm editing old code to just update a little thing. Was hoping for a cheap win.

Comment: @Grommit: Well, those render inside of Win32 window client areas, but you don't have to replace the whole GUI if you just want one window to repaint really quickly.

Comment: @Grommit: Added another idea.

Comment: Thanks. Already doing something equivalent.... And I get the frame rate hit every time an update happens that requires an update. It just seems to be a very slow call.